# PowerBI table does not show value when using "Direct query" table

Tags: powerbi

I have a "Many to one" relationship made between table A and table B.
Table A contain the fields Date, Product, SalesValue and table B contains: Product and Selection.
Sample data:
Table A (sorted top down on value):

```
Date       Product   Subproduct   Value
1-1-2020   Red       A            200
1-1-2020   Red       B            500
1-1-2020   Red       C            600
1-1-2020   Red       D            1500
```

Table B:

```
Product  Subproduct    Exclude
Red      A             Yes
Red      B             Yes
```

When I use "Import mode" for table B en make a many to one relationship on product.
My output will be the following when I make table visual:

```
Date       Product  Subproduct      Value   Exclude
1-1-2020   Red      A                200    Yes
1-1-2020   Red      B                500    Yes
1-1-2020   Red      C                600
1-1-2020   Red      D                1500
```

However when I use "direct query" mode for table B and use a many to one relationship on product.
My output will be the following:

```
Date       Product  Subproduct       Value  Exclude
1-1-2020   Red      A                200    Yes
1-1-2020   Red      B                500    Yes
1-1-2020   Red      C                
1-1-2020   Red      D
```

My goal is to get the following output, where I take the minimum of Value and exclude the producs that are indicated as "Excluded - Yes".

```
Date       Product   MinValue  
1-1-2020   Red       600
```

I am now using the following DAX formule

```
MinValue = Calculate(Min('TableA'[Value]),'TableB'[Excluded] <> "Yes")
```

However, with this formula I get the following output:

```
Date       Product   MinValue  
1-1-2020   Red
```

How could I get the desired output as "import mode" result with "direct query mode" in a measure?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create these below 2 **Measures**-

```
exclude = 

VAR current_row_product = MIN('Table A'[Product])
VAR current_row_sub_product = MIN('Table A'[Subproduct])

VAR find_table_B_exclude = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN('Table B'[Exclude]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table B'),
        'Table B'[Product] = current_row_product
            && 'Table B'[Subproduct] = current_row_sub_product
    )
)

RETURN find_table_B_exclude
```

```
exclude_final = 

VAR current_row_value = MIN('Table A'[Value])

VAR Table_A_min_value = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN('Table A'[Value]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table A'),
        'Table A'[exclude] <> "Yes"
    )
)

RETURN
if(
    [exclude] = "Yes",
    "Yes",
    IF(
        current_row_value = Table_A_min_value,
        "NO",
        "Yes"
    )
)
```

Here is the output for 2 Measure-

[image]

Now Apply a visual level filter to show only rows where **Final_exclude = NO** and the output is as below-

[image]

**-----PART-2----**

**In direct query, you need to use a query with left join as below-**

```
select A.Date,A.Product,A.Value,B.Selection
from table_a A
left join table_b B on A.Product = B.Product
```

The above query will keep value in your column **Value** for **Green** and **Yellow** where as you shown blank for them in your required output. If it is really a requirement, you can use this below query-

```
select 
A.Date,
A.Product,
case when B.Selection is null then null else A.Value end as Value,
B.Selection
from table_a A
left join table_b B on A.Product = B.Product
```

Comment: Hi mkRabbani, thanks for answering. I understand your solution. The problem is that I need to keep Table A in import mode, this table is a complex query, taking 10 minutes to run. Table 2, is a simple selection qry, which I need to be in direct qry mode because it is connected with PowerApps.

Comment: Then you can use Measure or Power Query Transformation for your required output.

Comment: HI mkRabbani, I have adjusted my requested with some more detail. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Hi @Zayfaya83, Please check first part of my updated answer.

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani, I am trying to reproduce your solution. But I cannot implement this line ```'Table A'[exclude] <> "Yes```, in the measure: exclude_final

Comment: Are you trying with Measure? Or column? Can you provide me the sample report pbix file? Here i can generate the expected output.

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani, I am creating your solution as measure, but Table A does not contain an Exclude column, this column is in Table B.I have not an example pbix file, don't know if this is possible, because we use direct qry for Table B. In sample file we cannot do this and there is no problem if the Table B is on import mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222235/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-zayfaya83).

Comment: Hi mkRabbani, If I have add to the example model the product Blue, the measure "Final_exclude"  with "No" value will only take the lowest of both products. In this case it should give the value for Red & Blue.